# Handle durations but no dates

Tags: r, date, time

What is the best way to mainpulate only durations in R ? I mean I have a string vector like:

```
> test
[1] "00:04:06" "00:04:02" "00:04:16" "00:03:51" "00:03:55"
```

and I want to convert it to some specific class, which will understand these durations. I know I can use for example `strptime`:

```
> strptime(test, format = '%H:%M:%S')
[1] "2016-05-02 00:04:06 UTC" "2016-05-02 00:04:02 UTC" "2016-05-02 00:04:16 UTC" "2016-05-02 00:03:51 UTC" "2016-05-02 00:03:55 UTC"
```

but this creates a real dates vectors with today's date. I'd like to avoid it since this can cause troubles in the future for my application and this is a 'wrong' info.

Comment: You can use `library(chron); chron(times=test)`

Comment: `luridate::as.duration()` should help!

Comment: `chron` handling of negative duration seems weaker than `lubridate`, but thanks for both alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
require(lubridate)
test<-c("00:04:06", "00:04:02", "00:04:16", "00:03:51", "00:03:55")
t2<-lapply(test,lubridate::hms)
as.numeric(unlist(t2))
```

Output:

```
[1]  6  2 16 51 55
```